# Python - In a ML code. Getting error : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, list

I was going thru some ML python code just try to understand what is does and how it works. I noticed a youtube video that took me to this code [random-forests-tutorials](https://github.com/random-forests/tutorials/blob/master/decision_tree.py). The code actually uses hard-coded Array/List. But if I use file as input, then it throws

```
IndexError: list index out of range in the print_tree function
```

could someone please help me with resolving this? I have not yet changed anything else in the program besides just pointing it to file as input instead of hard-coded Array.

I created this function to read the CSV data from HEADER and TRAINING files. But to read the TESTING data file i have similar function but am not reading row[5] as it does not exist. the number of columns of Testing data file is 1 short.

```
def getBackData(filename)
  with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
    rawReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    if "_training" in filename:
        parsed = ((row[0],
                   int(row[1]),
                   int(row[2]),
                   int(row[3]),
                   row[4],
                   row[5])
                  for row in rawReader)
    else:
        parsed = rawReader

    theData = list(parsed)
return theData
```

So in the code am using the variables as

```
training_data = fs.getBackData(fileToUse + "_training.dat")
header = fs.getBackData(fileToUse + "_header.dat")
testing_data =fs.getBackData(fileToUse + "_testing.dat")
```

Sample Data for Header is

```
  header = ["CYCLE", "PASSES", "FAILURES", "IGNORED", "STATUS", "ACCEPTANCE"]
```

Sample for Training Data is

```
"cycle1",10,5,1,"fail","discard"
"cycle2",7,9,0,"fail","discard"
"cycle3",14,2,0,"pass","accept"
```

Sample for Testing Data is

```
"cycle71",11,4,1,"failed"
"cycle72",16,0,0,"passed"
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant believe myself. I was wondering why was it so difficult to use a CSV file when every  thing else is so easy in Python. My bad, I am new to it. So I finally figured out what was causing the list out of bound.

1. the function getBackData to be used to Training DATA & Testing Data only.
2. Separate function required for Header and Testing Data. Because Header will have equal number of columns, still the data type will be String.

Actually, I was using the function getBackData for Header also. and it was returning the CSV (containing headers) in a 2D list. Typically thats what it does. this was causing the issue.

Headers were supposed to be read as header[index], instead the code was recognizing it as header[row][col]. thats what I missed. I assumed Python to be intelligent enough to understand if only 1 row is there in CSV it should return a 1-D array.

Deserves a smiley :-)